# Accepting Bitcoin Settlement for Business Invoices, Important Business Considerations

Tags: bitcoin-core, invoices

Our company is intending on accepting Bitcoin as a settlement option. Currently, we create invoices based on services we perform with 30 day payment terms and want to offer the option of settling the invoice in Bitcoin for an X% discount.

It's been very difficult finding a good definitive guide for this, so I'm attempting to get that going here. Would be open to 3rd party solutions, but also would like to know what to consider without 3rd parties.

What are the business considerations for starting to accept invoice settlements in bitcoin?

Comment: All you need in order to accept bitcoin payments is an address or addresses. Provide one address per invoice. Service recommendations on this site are not allowed.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open, as there is useful advice to give even ignoring the 3rd party solution aspect.

Comment: @PieterWuille appreciate that. I think this is essential knowledge for any business professional looking to accept Bitcoin as a payment option. I always look for stackexchange answers.

Comment: What software do you use for billing? What software do you use for accounting? Have you made your software? Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: @Mercedes we have our own software for invoicing and marking payments. It is not very sophisticated, but we do develop it internally and have access to the source code. Other accounting activities are outsourced, but that shouldn't apply here.

Comment: I can't suggest a particular library, but worst case, you simply need to have your node create addresses and parse their balance from your stack.